# Inside arrow on the right with outline border and boxshadow

Tags: css

I'm trying to add some `css3` styles on an element, basing on an image model.
After many search, I've been able to have a some results, but not all I need.

You can see on the following image : http://soultherapy.free.fr/img/css3_need_screen.png

[image]

=> on the top : the effects I'm trying to reproduce in `css3`
=> on the bottom : the effects I was able to realize with `css3` only : very very far from perfection ^^

As you can see, there are problems with border and shading of the right arrow...

Here is the `html` code :

```
<div class="span6">
   <a href="#" class="arrow-box">the text<b></b></a>
</div>
```

And the css code :

```
.arrow-box, .arrow-box:hover {        
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block; 
    font-weight: bold;     
    padding: 6px 12px 6px 30px;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px -18px;
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color: #5e98ba;  
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    box-shadow: 3px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.5);

    outline: 1px solid #5e98ba;

    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    border:1px solid #c4c7c9;
    border-left: 0;
    }  


.arrow-box:before{
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    left: 0px;
    top: 100%;
    border-width: 5px 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #315164 #315164 transparent transparent;
}

.arrow-box:after{
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    right: -10px;
    top: 0;
    border-width: 10px 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #5e98ba transparent transparent #5e98ba  ;
}
.arrow-box b {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    right: -10px;
    bottom: 0;
    border-width: 10px 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color:  transparent transparent #5e98ba #5e98ba ; 
}
```

Do you think what I'm trying to do is possible only with css3 ?
If it's the case, could you help me to find the correct `css3` code.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2cDnV/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know my solution does not look exactly like your image but might help you to get started.

You can play around the code a bit to get what you want and to bring elegance to it.

You can find the jsFiddle [here.](http://jsfiddle.net/kzvQq/4/)

HTML:

```
<div class="marginer">
    <div class="box">
        <div class="boxIn">This is text</div>
        <div class="boxArrowUp">
            <div class="boxArrowUpIn"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="boxArrowDown">
            <div class="boxArrowDownIn"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.marginer {
    margin: 20px;
}
.boxIn {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-right: 0;
    padding: 6px 12px 6px 30px;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 0px #5e98ba, 1px -1px 0px #5e98ba;
}
.box {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px -18px;
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color: #5e98ba;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    box-shadow: 8px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
.box:before {
    content:' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    left: 0px;
    top: 100%;
    border-width: 5px 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #315164 #315164 transparent transparent;
}
.boxArrowUp {
    content:' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    right: -10px;
    top: 0;
    border-width: 10px 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #5e98ba transparent transparent #5e98ba;
}
.boxArrowUpIn:before {
    content:' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    top: -10px;
    left: -5px;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    border-right: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #5e98ba, 0px -1px 0px #5e98ba;
}
.boxArrowUpIn:after {
    content:' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 2px;
    height: 20px;
    top: -11px;
    left: -1px;
    background: #5e98ba;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    -moz-transform:rotate(28deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(28deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(28deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(28deg);
    z-index: 2;
    box-shadow: 3px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
.boxArrowDown {
    content:' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    right: -10px;
    bottom: 0;
    border-width: 10px 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent #5e98ba #5e98ba;
}
.boxArrowDownIn:before {
    content:' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: -5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    border-right: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #5e98ba, 0px 0px 0px #5e98ba;
}
.boxArrowDownIn:after {
    content:' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 2px;
    height: 19px;
    bottom: -11px;
    left: -1px;
    background: #5e98ba;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    -moz-transform:rotate(332deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(332deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(332deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(332deg);
    z-index: 2;
    box-shadow: 1px 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}
```

I've played a bit with shadows and tranforms to achieve the result.

Let me know if it helped you.

Comment: If it solved your problem then you can mark this as an answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the final code to obtain exactly the same result as in the original image : http://jsfiddle.net/developpeuse_web/TSFMT/1/

HTML :

```
    <div class="box">
        <div class="left-shadow"></div>
        <div class="boxIn"></div>
        <div class="boxArrowUp">
            <div class="boxArrowUpIn"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="boxArrowDown">
            <div class="boxArrowDownIn"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS :

```
.left-shadow {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 23px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#333333), to(transparent));
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #333333, transparent);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #333333, transparent);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #333333, transparent);
    background-image: linear-gradient(left, #333333, transparent);
    opacity: 0.44;
    filter : alpha(opacity=44);
} 
.boxIn {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    border-right: 0;
    padding: 6px 12px 6px 30px;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 0px #5e98ba, 1px -1px 0px #5e98ba;
}

.box {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px -18px;
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color: #5e98ba;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.45));
}
.box:before {
    content:' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    left: 0px;
    top: 100%;
    border-width: 5px 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #315164 #315164 transparent transparent;
}
.boxArrowUp {
    content:' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    right: -10px;
    top: 0;
    border-width: 10px 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #5e98ba transparent transparent #5e98ba;
}
.boxArrowUpIn:before {
    content:' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    top: -10px;
    left: -5px;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    border-right: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #5e98ba, 0px -1px 0px #5e98ba;
}
.boxArrowUpIn:after {
    content:' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 2px;
    height: 20px;
    top: -11px;
    left: -1px;
    background: #5e98ba;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    -moz-transform:rotate(28deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(28deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(28deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(28deg);
    z-index: 2;
}
.boxArrowDown {
    content:' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    right: -10px;
    bottom: 0;
    border-width: 10px 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent #5e98ba #5e98ba;
}
.boxArrowDownIn:before {
    content:' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: -5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    border-right: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #5e98ba, 0px 0px 0px #5e98ba;
}
.boxArrowDownIn:after {
    content:' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 2px;
    height: 19px;
    bottom: -11px;
    left: -1px;
    background: #5e98ba;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    -moz-transform:rotate(332deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(332deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(332deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(332deg);
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Thanks Harshad !

Answer (score 0):

Thanks...of course it helped me a lot !
If it's not perfect, well it's very close :)

In complement, I've just found another way to generate shadow, by using "-webkit-filter: drop-shadow". So I've add this attribute to .box element, and remove the grey box-shadow on all other elements (.box, .boxArrowUpIn:after, .boxArrowDownIn:after ) : http://jsfiddle.net/developpeuse_web/TSFMT/

```
.marginer {
    margin: 20px;
}
.boxIn {
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
    border-right: 0;
    padding: 6px 12px 6px 30px;
    box-shadow: 1px 2px 0px #5e98ba, 1px -1px 0px #5e98ba;
}
.box {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 10px 10px 10px -18px;
    color: #fff !important;
    background-color: #5e98ba;
    /* -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
    box-shadow: 8px 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5); */
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.45));
}
.box:before {
    content:' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    left: 0px;
    top: 100%;
    border-width: 5px 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #315164 #315164 transparent transparent;
}
.boxArrowUp {
    content:' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    right: -10px;
    top: 0;
    border-width: 10px 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #5e98ba transparent transparent #5e98ba;
}
.boxArrowUpIn:before {
    content:' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    top: -10px;
    left: -5px;
    border-top: 1px solid #fff;
    border-right: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #5e98ba, 0px -1px 0px #5e98ba;
}
.boxArrowUpIn:after {
    content:' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 2px;
    height: 20px;
    top: -11px;
    left: -1px;
    background: #5e98ba;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    -moz-transform:rotate(28deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(28deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(28deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(28deg);
    z-index: 2;
    /* box-shadow: 3px 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5); */
}
.boxArrowDown {
    content:' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    right: -10px;
    bottom: 0;
    border-width: 10px 5px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: transparent transparent #5e98ba #5e98ba;
}
.boxArrowDownIn:before {
    content:' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 10px;
    height: 20px;
    bottom: -10px;
    left: -5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    border-right: 0px;
    box-shadow: 0px 2px 0px #5e98ba, 0px 0px 0px #5e98ba;
}
.boxArrowDownIn:after {
    content:' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 2px;
    height: 19px;
    bottom: -11px;
    left: -1px;
    background: #5e98ba;
    border-left: 1px solid #fff;
    -moz-transform:rotate(332deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(332deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(332deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(332deg);
    z-index: 2;
    /* box-shadow: 1px 4px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, .5); */
}
```

Don't know if it's a better solution for browsers compatibility, but looks a little bit cleaner.

I think the last detail I have to do is to add an inner shadow on the left border, and it will be exactly what I need. I'll post the final code here.

Thanks very much !

Answer (score 0):

Is it too late to enter the contest ?

The HTML

```
<div id="mysolution">MY SOLUTION<div id="arrow"></div></div>
```

The CSS

```
#mysolution {
    color: red;
    padding: 10px 9px 10px 25px;
    position: relative; 
    display: block;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 170px;
    height: 30px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#mysolution:after, #mysolution:before {
    content: " "; 
    display: block; 
    left: -20px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 80%; 
} 

#mysolution:before { 
    z-index: -2; 
    height: 30%;
    top: 11%;
    -webkit-transform: skewX(-35deg); 
    background-image: linear-gradient(55deg, black, rgb(94, 152, 186) 30%); 
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    border-top: 1px solid white;
    box-shadow: 1.52px -1px 0px #5e98ba, 4px 4px 5px rgb(110, 110, 110);
}

#mysolution:after { 
    z-index: -1; 
    height: 28%;
    bottom: 28.95%;
    -webkit-transform: skewX(35deg); 
    background-image: linear-gradient(125deg, black, rgb(94, 152, 186) 30%); 
    padding-right: .8px;
    border-right: 1px solid white;
    border-bottom: 1px solid white;
    box-shadow: 1.52px 1px 0px #5e98ba, 1.52px 0.5px 0px #5e98ba,-2px 4px 5px rgb(110, 110, 110);
}

#arrow {
    position: absolute;
    width: 0px;
    height: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    top: 37px;
    border-width: 5px 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #315164 #315164 transparent transparent;
    z-index: -3;
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(2px 2px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.45));
}
```

### [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SSeyR/embedded/result/)

Just trying to do it with less divs and less CSS. (And picking ideas from the work already done... :-)